# Gesture on gridview does not always work

Tags: android, gridview, calendar, gesture

I have a calendar with gridview and changing months should be working with gestures (flings) on the gridview. A fling from left to right goes to the previous month, and a fling from right to left should go to the next month. The first one works, the second one does not always work, it detects the left to right fling instead(40-50%). I am using a standard onfling function and I have two other buttons with arrows that indicate another option to change months. Those buttons work very well, and if I use the onfling function on an imageview or textview, or anything that isnt a gridview, it works very well.

```
    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 40;
        private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
            {
                //Log.i("Swipe", "Right to Left");
                //Log.i("Swipe", "Swipe rowid2" + selected_row_id2 + "set to true");
                gestureDirection = "rtl";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RTL", 3500);
                toast.show();
                return true;
            }
            else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
            {
                //Log.i("Swipe", "Left to Right");
                //Log.i("Swipe", "Swipe rowid" + selected_row_id2 + "set to false");
                gestureDirection = "ltr";
                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LTR", 3500);
                toast2.show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned it is a standard onFLing function, but the fling from right to left sometimes behaves as if I flinged from left to right and instead of changing to the next month it goes back to the previous month. It should impossible since `(e1.getX() - e2.getX())` should not allow this. I noticed that if my fling from right to left is short (but of course bigger than the SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) it always work, but for example if my fling's size is almost 3/4 screen it sometimes behaves incorrect. Another interesting thing, it always works on emulator, the problem is detected on phone.
Any one had this problem?

Comment: Hi did you sole this issue I am facing same problem now... Any help / Suggestions will be very help full to me please help...

Comment: Nope, tried a lot of workarounds, none of them worked.